How does one identify Pauli logicals in a hyperbolic surface code?
I understand how the Pauli X and Z logicals on the planar surface code work - they are stringlike operators between either the rough boundaries (in case of the Z logical) or between smooth boundaries (for X logical). I choose these boundaries in this order because I want the Z logical to commute with the X-type stabilizers and vice-versa.
My question is - how can one similarly identify the Pauli logicals for hyperbolic surface codes? What do these Pauli operators visually look like, given a tesselation of the hyperbolic plane? Since hyperbolic codes have constant rate, there must be multiple pairs.

To begin, note that the hyperbolic surface codes have to be defined on periodic hyperbolic surfaces, so you should think of them analogously to toric codes, and not planar codes with rough/smooth boundaries.
If you look at section IIID of https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04029, you'll notice something unusual about the hyperbolic codes they construct: for a given tiling, if you try to make a larger hyperbolic surface, the only way to make this tiling consistent with periodic boundary conditions and the hyperbolic metric is to increase the genus of the surface.
What this means is that for, e.g., the {5,4} tiling, if you increase the number of tiles you increase the number of non-contractable loops. The logical operators are still an independent set of non-contractable loops of X and Z operators, just like for the euclidean toric code. This is why the rate is constant--the number of non-contractable loops is proportional to the number of tiles.

Thanks! So I would visualize these X and Z operators also as non-contractible loops that intersect in odd number of edges. This works for periodic surfaces.
But if we consider open boundaries and look at a finite disk of a compactified surface, what do the end points of these logicals look like? How does one convert the code to this planar version?

@clearski You can take a look at Fig. 10 of the paper I linked. In general, when you unfold a genus $g$ surface, you'll get g pairs of identified edges that you have to cut. If you make these edges alternate between "rough" and "smooth" boundaries, you can get a bunch of non-equivalent logical operators that connect different pairs of rough (or pairs of smooth) boundaries. But I do want to emphasize that you are not supposed to do this for the hyperbolic surface codes. They only work on periodic surfaces. When you introduce boundaries, you end up significantly reducing the distance.

ok, thanks. Is the distance reduction because now the loops don't go through the bulk of the surface, especially as the rate (k/n) increases?
Are there other ways of implementing hyperbolic codes in a 2D surface without cutting boundaries?

@JahanClaes what's the definition of a periodic surface?...I assume a torus is periodic.

@unknown A torus is indeed periodic. But you could have a higher-genus periodic surface, e.g. if you imagine in Fig. 10 that when you go off the right side boundary you come back on the left side, if you go off the upper-right-diagonal boundary you come back on the lower-left-diagonal side, etc.

@JahanClaes hmmm...I thought diagonally opposite edges are always identified together...this would make everything periodic which doesn't seem right.  What am I missing?
